# problem with datePicker, title initialization is funky

Tags: android

So I have reached the end of my rope when it comes to this dang
datePicker dialog that I am working with. I have made it through 7
different activities within my app and have not encountered a single
problem until I reached the datePicker. My problem consists of two
elements: 1) The dang title of my datePicker displays Wednesday,
December 31, 0002 when called. The datePicker itself displays
correctly, but not the title, and I have not altered the title one
bit. When you change the date the title changes to the correct
information except for.... 2) It appears as if the days of the week
are off by one (for today it says Monday, February 22, 2011). So I am
going to post my entire code within this activity and if anyone has
any ideas any help is much appreciated.  The issue is going to be in
the onCreateDialog or onPrepareDialog methods.  If i need to remove
any of the other extraneous init methods I will do so, but I would
like to verify that I am not causing problems anywhere else within
this activity.

```
public class QuizSettingsActivity extends QuizActivity {
   SharedPreferences mGameSettings;
   static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
   static final int PASSWORD_DIALOG_ID = 1;

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.settings);

       //Retrieve the shared preferences
       mGameSettings = getSharedPreferences(GAME_PREFERENCES,
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       //Initialize nickname entry
       initNicknameEntry();
       //Initialize email entry
       initEmailEntry();
       //Initialize the password chooser
       initPasswordChooser();
       //Initialize date picker
       initDatePicker();
       //Initialize spinner
       initGenderSpinner();
       //Initialize clear
       initClear();

   }//end of on Create


   //Initialize clear
   private void initClear() {
       Button clear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BTN_Clear);
       clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               EditText nickname =
(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET_Nickname);
               nickname.setText("");
               EditText email =
(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET_Email);
               email.setText("");
               TextView dob =
(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TV_DOB_Info);

dob.setText(R.string.settings_dob_not_set);

               Editor editor = mGameSettings.edit();
               editor.remove(GAME_PREFERENCES_DOB);
               editor.remove(GAME_PREFERENCES_GENDER);
               //editor.clear();
               editor.commit();
           }//End of onClick
       });//end of on click listener
   }//end of clear method


   //Handles logging upon leaving settings screen
   @Override
   protected void onDestroy(){
       Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "SHARED PREFERENCES");
       Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Nickname is:  "
               + mGameSettings.getString(GAME_PREFERENCES_NICKNAME,
"Not Set"));
       Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Email is:  "
               + mGameSettings.getString(GAME_PREFERENCES_EMAIL, "Not
Set"));
       Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Gender (U=0, M=1, F=2) is:  " +
               + mGameSettings.getInt(GAME_PREFERENCES_GENDER, 0));
       //Don't save password as of yet
       Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Password is:  "
               + mGameSettings.getString(GAME_PREFERENCES_PASSWORD,
"Not Set"));
       //Don't save dob yet
       Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "DOB is:  "
               + DateFormat.format("MMMM, dd, yyyy",
                       mGameSettings.getLong(GAME_PREFERENCES_DOB,
0)));
       super.onDestroy();
   }//end of on Destroy




   //Initialize spinner
   private void initGenderSpinner() {
        //Configuring spinner controls...load spinner
       final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)
findViewById(R.id.Spinner_Gender);
       ArrayAdapter<?> adapter =
ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
               R.array.gender, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
       if(mGameSettings.contains(GAME_PREFERENCES_GENDER)){

spinner.setSelection(mGameSettings.getInt(GAME_PREFERENCES_GENDER,
0));
       }
       //Handle spinner selection
       spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View
itemSelected,
                   int selectedItemPosition, long selectedId){
               Editor editor = mGameSettings.edit();
               editor.putInt(GAME_PREFERENCES_GENDER,
selectedItemPosition);
               editor.commit();
           }

           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){
           }
       });
   }//end of spinner


   //Initialize Date Picker
   private void initDatePicker() {
       //Set Date Info
       TextView dobInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_DOB_Info);
       if(mGameSettings.contains(GAME_PREFERENCES_DOB)){
           dobInfo.setText(DateFormat.format("MMMM dd, yyyy",
                   mGameSettings.getLong(GAME_PREFERENCES_DOB, 0)));
       }else {
           dobInfo.setText(R.string.settings_dob_not_set);
       }
       //Handle date picking dialog
       Button pickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button_DOB);
       pickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
               /*Toast.makeText(QuizSettingsActivity.this,
                       "TODO: Launch DatePicker Dialog",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
           }//end of onClick
       });//end of OnClick Listener
   }//end of date picker


   @Override
   protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
       switch(id){
       case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
           final TextView dob =
(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TV_DOB_Info);
           DatePickerDialog dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                   new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                       public void onDateSet(DatePicker view,
                           int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
{
                           Time dateOfBirth = new Time();
                           dateOfBirth.set(dayOfMonth, monthOfYear,
year);
                           long dtDob = dateOfBirth.toMillis(true);
                           dob.setText(DateFormat.format("MMMM dd,
yyyy", dtDob));

                           Editor editor = mGameSettings.edit();
                           editor.putLong(GAME_PREFERENCES_DOB,
dtDob);
                           editor.commit();
                       }//end of onDateSet
           },0,0,0);
           return dateDialog;

       case PASSWORD_DIALOG_ID:
           //build dialog inflate/load
           LayoutInflater inflater =
(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
                   Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           final View layout =
inflater.inflate(R.layout.password_dialog,
                   (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.root));
           final EditText p1 =
(EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.EditText_Pwd1);
           final EditText p2 =
(EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.EditText_Pwd2);
           final TextView error = (TextView)
layout.findViewById(R.id.TextView_PwdProblem);
           p2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {//adding
import adds beforeTextChanged
                                                         //&
onTextChanged methods
                   String strPass1 = p1.getText().toString();
                   String strPass2 = p2.getText().toString();
                   if (strPass1.equals(strPass2)) {
                       error.setText(R.string.settings_pwd_equal);
                   } else {

error.setText(R.string.settings_pwd_not_equal);
                   }
               }

               @Override//added with import of afterTextChanged
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int
start,
                       int count, int after) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               }

               @Override//added with import of afterTextChanged
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                       int before, int count) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               }
           });//end of text changed listener
           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new
AlertDialog.Builder(this);
           builder.setView(layout);
           builder.setTitle(R.string.settings_button_pwd);
           builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                   new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int
whichButton) {
                   // dismiss and remove the Dialog, so it
                   // cannot be used again (no cached info)

QuizSettingsActivity.this.removeDialog(PASSWORD_DIALOG_ID);
               }//end of onClick
           });//end of on click listener

           builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                   new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
{
                   TextView passwordInfo =
                       (TextView)
findViewById(R.id.TV_Password_Info);
                   String strPassword1 = p1.getText().toString();
                   String strPassword2 = p2.getText().toString();
                   if (strPassword1.equals(strPassword2)) {
                       Editor editor = mGameSettings.edit();
                       editor.putString(GAME_PREFERENCES_PASSWORD,
strPassword1);
                       editor.commit();

passwordInfo.setText(R.string.settings_pwd_set);
                   } else {
                       Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Passwords do not match. Not
saving. Keeping old password (if set).");
                   }
                   //dismiss and remove the dialog so it
                   // cannot be used again using removeDialog

QuizSettingsActivity.this.removeDialog(PASSWORD_DIALOG_ID);
               }//end of onClick
           });//end of onClick listener
           //create and call dialog and return it
           AlertDialog passwordDialog = builder.create();
           return passwordDialog;
       }//end of switch
       return null;
   }//end of Dialog on CreateDialog method



   @Override
   protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog){
       super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
       switch(id){
       case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
           //Handle any date picker dialog initialization here
           DatePickerDialog dateDialog = (DatePickerDialog) dialog;
           int iDay, iMonth, iYear;
           //check for date of birth preference
           if(mGameSettings.contains(GAME_PREFERENCES_DOB)){
               //retrieve dob setting from preferences
               long msBirthDate =
mGameSettings.getLong(GAME_PREFERENCES_DOB, 0);
               Time dateOfBirth = new Time();
               dateOfBirth.set(msBirthDate);
               iDay = dateOfBirth.monthDay;
               iMonth = dateOfBirth.month;
               iYear = dateOfBirth.year;
           } else {
               final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
               //Today's date fields
               iDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
               iMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
               iYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

               //dateDialog.setTitle("Birthday");
               //dateDialog.updateDate(2000,11,25);

           }
           //set the date in the date picker to the date of birth
           //OR to the current date
           dateDialog.updateDate(iYear, iMonth, iDay);
           return;

       case PASSWORD_DIALOG_ID:
           return;
       }//end of switch
   }//end of onPrepareDialog method


   //Initialize Password Chooser
   private void initPasswordChooser() {
       // Set password info
       TextView passwordInfo = (TextView)
findViewById(R.id.TV_Password_Info);
       if(mGameSettings.contains(GAME_PREFERENCES_PASSWORD)){
           passwordInfo.setText(R.string.set_password);
       }else{
           passwordInfo.setText(R.string.settings_pwd_not_set);
       }
       //Handle password setting dialog
       Button setPassword = (Button)
findViewById(R.id.Button_Password);
       setPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               showDialog(PASSWORD_DIALOG_ID);
               /*Toast.makeText(QuizSettingsActivity.this, "TODO:
Launch Password Dialog",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
           }
       });
   }//End of Password Chooser


   //Initialize Email entry
   private void initEmailEntry() {
       // Save Email
       final EditText emailText = (EditText)
findViewById(R.id.ET_Email);
       if (mGameSettings.contains(GAME_PREFERENCES_EMAIL)){

emailText.setText(mGameSettings.getString(GAME_PREFERENCES_EMAIL,
""));
       }
       emailText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
       public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
           if((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN ||
                   event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) &&
                   (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || keyCode ==
KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB)){
               Editor editor = mGameSettings.edit();
               editor.putString(GAME_PREFERENCES_EMAIL,
emailText.getText().toString());
               editor.commit();
               return true;
           }
           return false;
       }
       });
   }//end of email


   //Initialize Nickname entry
   private void initNicknameEntry() {
       // Save Nickname
       final EditText nicknameText = (EditText)
findViewById(R.id.ET_Nickname);
       if (mGameSettings.contains(GAME_PREFERENCES_NICKNAME)){

nicknameText.setText(mGameSettings.getString(GAME_PREFERENCES_NICKNAME,
""));
       }
       nicknameText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
       public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
           if((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN ||
                   event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) &&
                   (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || keyCode ==
KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB)){
               String strNickname =
nicknameText.getText().toString();
               Editor editor = mGameSettings.edit();
               editor.putString(GAME_PREFERENCES_NICKNAME,
strNickname);
               editor.commit();
               return true;
           }
           return false;
       }
       });
   }//End of nickname

}//end of QuizSettingsActivity
```

I have also tried to setTitle, but that only works up until the date is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FROSTYSMOOTH,

I believe what you are seeing is an incompatibility between the Android `Time` and `Calendar` data types you are using.

The ENUM values for the days of the week are inconsistent between them...

Monday in a `Calendar` object has a value of 0x2 [SEE HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#MONDAY).

Monday in a `Time` object has a value of 0x1 [SEE HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#MONDAY).

So when you try to set a `Calendar` object with values from a `Time` object, you will be a day off.

You need to sort out when each is being used an adjust accordingly or stick to a single Date/Time object so you won't run into these issues.

I hope I was able to help, good luck!

Comment: Many thanks...I am sure this will not be my last post around this neck of the woods.  I will re-work some of this and see where it leads me.  Although I have yet to do so do you know if this will fix the funky title aspect that I am experiencing as well?

Comment: I was a little confused with the first part of your question.  What exactly is not displaying correctly in the #1 portion of your question?

Comment: Well when the datePicker initializes off the button click it displays: Wednesday, December 31, 0002 as the title up until the date is changed and then the title displays the correct information.